# How to programmatically share calendar from one iCloud user account to another iCloud user account in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, icloud, eventkit

How to programmatically share calendar from one iCloud user account to another iCloud user account in iOS?  Which Cocoa Touch classes would be used?  Would it be a topic about iCloud or EventKit?